# What's the connection between Aravos and Heaven?

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, etymology, heaven

What is the connection between the Aravos we take as part of the daled minim on Sukkos and the Aravos of Heaven which the Almighty "rides" on?

[Tehillim (68:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.68.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)

> שִׁירוּ לֵאלֹהִים זַמְּרוּ שְׁמוֹ סֹלּו**ּ לָרֹכֵב בָּעֲרָבוֹת**
> בְּיָהּ שְׁמוֹ וְעִלְזוּ לְפָנָיו ׃  -Sing to God, chant hymns to His
> name; extol Him who **rides on the *aravos***; the LORD is His name.
> Exult in His presence—

Comment: Where is that translation from?

Answer (score 3):

The *gemarra* in [Chagigah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.5) says that there are seven *rekiyos*, loosely translated as seven Heavens.

> ר"ל אמר שבעה ואלו הן וילון רקיע שחקים זבול מעון מכון ערבות
>
> Reish Lakish said: There are seven firmaments, and they are as follows: Vilon, Rakia, Sheḥakim, Zevul, Ma’on, Makhon, and Aravot.

One of them is called *Aravos*. The *gemarra* [goes on](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.12) to describe what's in this Heaven, and [cites](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.14) the verse you bring as proof that there is such a Heaven.

Now, it could be a coincidence that there's a Heaven called *Aravos*, and we use something called *Aravos* in our *Arbah Minim*. However, **Rabbeinu Bachaye** tries to make a connection. In his [**Kad HaKemach** § ערבה](https://www.sefaria.org/Kad_HaKemach%2C_Willow.1.1), he has an entire essay on this topic. It's mostly *kabbalistic*, so it's beyond my comprehension. However, I'll share one piece which is interesting. He explains the connection to this Heaven and *Hoshana Rabbah*, the seventh day of Sukkos, in which the *aravos* play a major role.

> וכדי להורות שלטנותו יתברך על **הגלגל השביעי** הוא ערבות לכך קבעו לנו רבותינו חכמי האמת ז"ל מצות ערבה **ביום שביעי**, ונתחייב כל אחד ואחד מישראל ליטול בידו ערבה ביום זה מלבד הערבה שבלולב שהיא רומזת אל הענין הזה בעצמו
>
> In order to teach us that Hashem has dominion over this **seventh sphere**, which is *aravos*, our Rabbis, those knowledgeable in the truth, enacted the *mitzvah* of the *arava* on **the seventh day**. Each Jewish person is obligated to take in their hands an *aravah* on this day, besides the *aravah* in their four species, which symbolizes this matter itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Yitzchok Breitowitz once explained that the arava represents the Jew without Torah and massim tovim as the Medrash explains. However, the Aravos also represents Moshe and Ahron . The Arava also represents the potential in every Jew to grow,unlike the other species which can point to their past accomplishments.  Therefore, Rabbi Breitwoitz explains that the Arvos sits under the Kisei Hakavod because it represents the humble Jew who does not feel entitled and has fear of HaShem. This type of person is considered close to HaShem.

I would add my own idea that the arava is extremely reliant on water to flourish and not dry up. Metaphorically water represents Torah and the arava represnts a person who is thirsting for Torah ,such a person is closest to the source.